# What is the haskell equivalent of an interface?

Tags: haskell, design-patterns, interface

I would like to implement modules that are guaranteed to export a similar set of functions.

For the sake of an example: Suppose I want to translate a word. Every word is mapped from the source language (let's say `English`) to the target language (let's say `Spanish` and `Russian`).

My main application would import the models for Spanish and Russian and chooses a default model, Russian. I would like to guarantee, that each model has:

- a function `translateToken :: String -> String`
- a function `translatePhrase :: String -> String`

in which the specific behaviour is implemented.

How do I do this?

**Edit**, regarding Lee's answer:
*How do i create data types with record syntax that contain functions that use guards?*

```
-- let's suppose I want to use a function with guards in a record.
-- how can and should i define that?

data Model  = Model { translateToken :: String -> String}

-- idea 1) should I define the functions separately, like this?
-- how do I do this in a way that does not clutter the module?
f l
  | l == "foo" = "bar"

main :: IO ()
main = print $ translateToken x "foo"
  where
    x = Model {translateToken=f}
    -- idea 2) define the function when creating the record,
    -- despite the syntax error, this seems messy:
    -- x = Model {name=(f l | l == "foo" = "bar")}

-- idea 3) update the record later
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can create a type containing the functions you want e.g.

```
data Model = Model { translateToken :: String -> String,
                     translatePhrase :: String -> String }
```

then create values for Spanish and Russian.

Comment: I'm curious, why type with records as opposed to a typeclass?

Comment: @MichalCharemza Because when you use a type class `C` used as a Java interface, you will soon be tripped by the fact that `C` is not a type, and start defining an existential type around `C` like `data T = forall t. C t => T t`. And this is a well-known Haskell [anti-pattern](https://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/). Note: I mostly agree with Luke Palmer in that this is often overkill, and does not gain anything w.r.t. using a basic record with functions. In some specific cases, however, I do think the "antipattern" is justified.

Comment: @MichalCharemza - I think this approach is simpler since you don't need to create a new type for each translation instance (i.e. `SpanishTranslation`, `RussianTranslation`). Another advantage is you can put records into collections and manipulate them all together which is awkward with type classes. I also think this is closer to the use of interfaces in OO language where behaviour is coupled to the receiver rather than a type.

Comment: I don't know if this anti-pattern is relevant for me. If I would like to get a list of the different tranlastions I could create a type that lists them explicitly, right? If type classes define a behaviour and I should not use them, what else are they good for?

Comment: @inktrap - What would the type of your list be? With this solution it would be `[Model]` - if you use typeclasses you will need to use existential types to put `SpanishTranslation`, `RussianTranslation` etc. into the same list which is much more complicated. Type classes are for overloading, not data abstraction.

Comment: @Lee 
 
Alright, so I can overload an operator or a function, that makes sense. So isn't the literature misleading when they compare typeclasses to interfaces? I myself would have answered it like Frank Schmitt, had I read the stuff he read more attentively … and I have a follow up question regarding your answer (which I am going to append to my question).

Comment: @inktrap - Yes I think it is misleading to compare OO interfaces and type classes. Type classes are implicit function parameters resolved based on the type. OO interfaces couple the dictionary to the identity of the reciever and are used for information hiding. You should probably move your edit into a new question so it will get more attention.

Answer (score 3):

That would be typeclasses. From [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses): 
"Typeclasses are more like interfaces. "

You'd define your own typeclass (untested):

```
  class Translation a where
    translateToken :: a -> String -> String
    translatePhrase :: a -> String -> String
```

and implement it as

```
  instance Translation Spanish where
     translateToken = spanishTranslateToken
     translatePhrase = spanishTranslatePhrase
```

See also [Real Word Haskell on typeclasses](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-typeclasses.html)

Comment: a little typo, it's supposed to be `instance Translation Spanish where` instead of `instance Spanish Translation where`

Comment: @FrankSchmitt As I wrote in a comment on Lee's answer: That would have been my answer, if I had read the literature as attentively as you did. Thank you, I appreciate it! However, I am going to accept Lee's answer because “Type classes are for overloading, not data abstraction.”

Answer (score -3):

A `class`, sometimes referred to as a "type class". Don't get this confused with your usual OO-classes though, Haskell classes don't have data, and generally don't have implementations (with the exception of generic defaults).

Comment: Not my downvote, but what do you mean by "[classes] generally don't have implementations (with the exception of generic defaults)"? Do you mean that many implementations are automatically derived versus written by hand?

Comment: I mean classes only define the type of the function, they don't define the function itself. This is unlike C++ classes which often but not always have both types and implementations